# New replacement rear shocks/strut replacement cartridges are not available, can I have them rebuilt?

Tags: suspension, mitsubishi

1986 Mitsubishi Starion ESI-R Turbo

Comment: Google says they are available>>>https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=ht6uXqLWKMKwtQWkpKfwBw&q=1986+Mitsubishi+Starion+ESI-R+Turbo+rear+shocks&oq=1986+Mitsubishi+Starion+ESI-R+Turbo+rear+shocks&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCCEQqwI6BQghEKABOggIIRAWEB0QHjoHCCEQChCgAVCaDViFLGC-MmgAcAB4AIABZ4gB_geSAQQxMi4xmAEAoAECoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiisenX_JfpAhVCWK0KHSTSCX4Q4dUDCAk&uact=5

Comment: Fronts are available, and f/r sets of lowering coil set ups, around $900 average, and I don't want to lower car, that already had clearance issue with front ground effects/factory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you can find a place capable or prepared to do the work.

The price may change depending on if you remove the parts or expect them to.

Comment: I have never seen ads for rebuilding services for this, but saw in another post it could be done. Hoped would find someone with same vehicle who could direct me to national chain that does this kind of work. I would have a professional mechanic do the removal and re-installation.

Comment: There may be a swap service, you send in your busted ones and get refurbs instead of having yours rebuilt. Faster.

Answer (score 1):

Are you in the state or Canada because if you are in Canada you have got two options one is Ontario more often than not items like shocks are way way cheaper.

Option two is Carid or Rock Auto, ask for a Canadian or America or Mexican made part as there is no broker fee on them when they cross in to the country I have saved thousands of dollars buying parts this way.

I have never heard of rebuilt ones before.

Comment: I am in the US, but Rock Auto was recommended for parts by a Conquest owner, who also owns his own repair shop. He would get the job if I could locate OEM type parts. I will look into your suggestion, thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

There's a company in the states that will take your old sealed struts and modify them to accept strut inserts.

https://www.racetep.com/automaker/starion/starion-rear-strut-problem-cured.html

I'm not sure of any other services that do this but it's worth hitting up some suspension shops in your area to see if they could do it.